# Accessing 5-byte struct is much slower than 8-byte

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, benchmarking

I have a code which updates an array based on values in another, small array.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
  {
    var c = cards[i];
    result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
  }
```

Where `c` is a struct that is a pair of bytes representing cards from a deck.
`one` is an array size of 52 (with entries for each of 52 cards from a deck)

I wrote a benchmark to profile this code:

```
private void TestCards2(int testRepetitions, float[] result, float[] one, Cards[] cards)
{
  for (var r = 0; r < testRepetitions; r++)
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
}
```

Setting `testRepetitions` = 25 million, and using array of 256 elements (`result.Length = 256`), it runs in about 8.5 seconds on my machine.

Here is the `Cards` struct:

```
struct Cards
{
  public byte C0;
  public byte C1;

  public Cards(byte c0, byte c1)
  {
    C0 = c0;
    C1 = c1;
  }
}
```

When I modify that struct to hold 5 cards (5 bytes), the same benchmark now takes ~13s.
Why would that happen? The computation is the same, remaining 3 cards are unused, and all arrays are small enough to fit in L1 cache.

What is even stranger, is that if I further change Cards to now hold 8 bytes, benchmark is now faster, taking ~10 seconds.

My Setup:

```
VS 2015 Update 3.
.NET 4.6.2
Release Build x64
CPU: Haswell i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz
```

Here are exact timings I got:

```
Test With 2 Cards. Time = 8582 ms
Test With 5 Cards. Time = 12910 ms
Test With 8 Cards. Time = 10180 ms
```

What is going on here?

Benchmark Code:

```
class TestAdjustment
  {
    public void Test()
    {
      using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

      var size = 256;

      float[] one = ArrayUtils.CreateRandomFloatArray(size:52);
      int[] card0 = ArrayUtils.RandomIntArray(size, minValue:0, maxValueInclusive:51);
      int[] card1 = ArrayUtils.RandomIntArray(size, minValue: 0, maxValueInclusive: 51);

      Cards[] cards = CreateCardsArray(card0, card1);
      Cards5[] cards5 = CreateCards5Array(card0, card1);
      Cards8[] cards8 = CreateCards8Array(card0, card1);

      float[] result = ArrayUtils.CreateRandomFloatArray(size);
      float[] resultClone = result.ToArray(); 


      var testRepetitions = 25*1000*1000;

      var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();


      TestCards2(testRepetitions, result, one, cards);
      WriteLine($"Test With 2 Cards. Time = {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
      result = resultClone.ToArray(); //restore original array from the clone, so that next method works on the same data
      sw.Restart();


      TestCards5(testRepetitions, result, one, cards5);
      WriteLine($"Test With 5 Cards. Time = {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
      result = resultClone.ToArray();
      sw.Restart();


      TestCards8(testRepetitions, result, one, cards8);
      WriteLine($"Test With 8 Cards. Time = {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");


    }



    private void TestCards2(int testRepetitions, float[] result, float[] one, Cards[] cards)
    {
      for (var r = 0; r < testRepetitions; r++)
        for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
          var c = cards[i];
          result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
        }
    }

    private void TestCards5(int testRepetitions, float[] result, float[] one, Cards5[] cards)
    {
      for (var r = 0; r < testRepetitions; r++)
        for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
          var c = cards[i];
          result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
        }
    }


    private void TestCards8(int testRepetitions, float[] result, float[] one, Cards8[] cards)
    {
      for (var r = 0; r < testRepetitions; r++)
        for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
          var c = cards[i];
          result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
        }
    }


    private Cards[] CreateCardsArray(int[] c0, int[] c1)
    {
      var result = new Cards[c0.Length];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        result[i] = new Cards((byte)c0[i], (byte)c1[i]);

      return result;
    }

    private Cards5[] CreateCards5Array(int[] c0, int[] c1)
    {
      var result = new Cards5[c0.Length];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        result[i] = new Cards5((byte)c0[i], (byte)c1[i]);

      return result;
    }

    private Cards8[] CreateCards8Array(int[] c0, int[] c1)
    {
      var result = new Cards8[c0.Length];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        result[i] = new Cards8((byte)c0[i], (byte)c1[i]);

      return result;
    }
  }


  struct Cards
  {
    public byte C0;
    public byte C1;

    public Cards(byte c0, byte c1)
    {
      C0 = c0;
      C1 = c1;
    }
  }

  struct Cards5
  {
    public byte C0, C1, C2, C3, C4;

    public Cards5(byte c0, byte c1)
    {
      C0 = c0;
      C1 = c1;
      C2 = C3 = C4 = 0;
    }
  }

  struct Cards8
  {
    public byte C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7;


    public Cards8(byte c0, byte c1)
    {
      C0 = c0;
      C1 = c1;
      C2 = C3 = C4 = C5 = C6 = C7 = 0;
    }
  }
```

*Edit*
I've rerun the benchmark again, with 100 million iterations. Here are the results:

```
Test With 5 Cards. Time = 52245 ms
Test With 8 Cards. Time = 40531 ms
```

And in reverse order:

```
Test With 8 Cards. Time = 41041 ms
Test With 5 Cards. Time = 52034 ms
```

Running it on Surface Pro 4 (Skylake i7-6650U Turbo-boosted to ~3.4ghz):

```
Test With 8 Cards. Time = 47913 ms
Test With 5 Cards. Time = 55182 ms
```

So the difference persists and doesn't depend on the order.

I also ran profiling using Intel VTune, and it shows CPI of `0.3` for "5 cards" version, and `0.27` for "8 cards".

**Edit2** Added ArrayUtils class for creating initial random arrays.

```
 public static class ArrayUtils
  {
    static Random rand = new Random(137);

    public static float[] CreateRandomFloatArray(int size)
    {
      var result = new float[size];
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        result[i] = (float) rand.NextDouble();

      return result;
    }

    public static int[] RandomIntArray(int size, int minValue, int maxValueInclusive)
    {
      var result = new int[size];
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        result[i] = rand.Next(minValue, maxValueInclusive + 1);

      return result;

    }
  }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Test With 2 Cards takes the most time to complete, while Test With 8 Cards is the fastest one. I even don't know how to explain this :) Probably, your case it is related to shallow copying in this line: `var c = cards[i];`. It takes more time to shallow copy a struct having 8 properties than having 5 or 2 byte properties.

Comment: @Yeldar In my benchmarks 5-byte struct is slower than 8 byte, while 2 byte is fastest.

Comment: Bench-marking such *very* fast code is excessively difficult.  The difference between the 2 and 8 test is only 0.25 nanoseconds per assignment, not even a nice multiple of the clock speed.  Just reorder the tests to get an arbitrary different result.  What you are *really* testing is your machine's ability to keep the processor cooled down enough.  Looks like it is a bit slow to turn the fan on, that's not unusual.  If you want a more consistent result then don't turn up the heat so much, 25 million doesn't make it better.  And open the case and suck out the dust bunnies.

Comment: @HansPassant I failed to mention that CPU is running in turbo mode @ 4.0GHz, so that 0.25ns would be 1 clock tick. I have also reran the benchmark again twice, with 100 million iteration each, and changing the order of computation as suggested. The difference still persists. See the updated question.

Comment: Okay, so you are chasing a single clock cycle.  You ought to remove "much slower" from your question title :)  It is going to be *very* hard to find, you'll need every trick that VTune has to offer, CPI isn't nearly  good enough.  Bigger issue, assuming you do find it, is what you're going to do about it in your C# code.  Absolutely nothing you can do about exactly where the branch targets are located and exactly how a memory allocation aligns with the L1 and TLB caches.  If you want somebody else to run this benchmark then post the ArrayUtils code.

Comment: @HansPassant It is much slower - 40 vs 52 seonds. I'm not at all proficient with VTune so I'm not going to try to find the root cause there. Also, this issue arose because of a similar piece of code in my program just ran considerably faster when using 2-byte vs 5-byte structs. What is surprising to me is that 8-byte structs are also faster than 5-byte.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's all about unaligned memory access. The unaligned memory ready latency is greater than the aligned memory read latency. To complete the experiment, let's add structs `Cards3`, `Cards4` and so on. And let's look how the corresponded arrays are represented in memory.

[image]

Next, let's improve your benchmark.

1. We will use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet) (this tool will do a lot of benchmarking routine like warmup, auto-selection of iteration amount, statistics calculation, and so on).
2. We will do our benchmark for all the `Cards2`..`Cards8` arrays, not only 3 of them.
3. Also we will check all the JIT compilers for the Full .NET Framework (LegacyJIT-x86, LegacyJIT-x64, RyuJIT-x64) and Mono.

Here is my environment:

```
Host Process Environment Information:
BenchmarkDotNet.Core=v0.9.9.0
OS=Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Processor=Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4810MQ CPU 2.80GHz, ProcessorCount=8
Frequency=2728068 ticks, Resolution=366.5598 ns, Timer=TSC
CLR1=MS.NET 4.0.30319.42000, Arch=64-bit RELEASE [RyuJIT]
CLR2=Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0, Arch=32-bit
GC=Concurrent Workstation
JitModules=clrjit-v4.6.1080.0
```

And my results:

```
 Method | Platform |       Jit | Toolchain | Runtime |    Median |    StdDev |
------- |--------- |---------- |---------- |-------- |---------- |---------- |
     C2 |     Host |      Host |      Mono |    Mono | 3.9230 ns | 0.0532 ns |
     C3 |     Host |      Host |      Mono |    Mono | 4.8223 ns | 0.0920 ns |
     C4 |     Host |      Host |      Mono |    Mono | 5.9149 ns | 0.1207 ns |
     C5 |     Host |      Host |      Mono |    Mono | 6.3981 ns | 0.0913 ns |
     C6 |     Host |      Host |      Mono |    Mono | 7.1179 ns | 0.1222 ns |
     C7 |     Host |      Host |      Mono |    Mono | 7.6318 ns | 0.1269 ns |
     C8 |     Host |      Host |      Mono |    Mono | 8.4650 ns | 0.1497 ns |
     C2 |      X64 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 2.3515 ns | 0.0150 ns |
     C3 |      X64 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 4.2553 ns | 0.0700 ns |
     C4 |      X64 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 1.4366 ns | 0.0385 ns |
     C5 |      X64 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 2.3688 ns | 0.0359 ns |
     C6 |      X64 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 2.3684 ns | 0.0404 ns |
     C7 |      X64 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 3.0404 ns | 0.0664 ns |
     C8 |      X64 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 1.4510 ns | 0.0333 ns |
     C2 |      X64 |    RyuJit |      Host |    Host | 1.9281 ns | 0.0306 ns |
     C3 |      X64 |    RyuJit |      Host |    Host | 2.1183 ns | 0.0348 ns |
     C4 |      X64 |    RyuJit |      Host |    Host | 1.9395 ns | 0.0397 ns |
     C5 |      X64 |    RyuJit |      Host |    Host | 2.7706 ns | 0.0387 ns |
     C6 |      X64 |    RyuJit |      Host |    Host | 2.6471 ns | 0.0513 ns |
     C7 |      X64 |    RyuJit |      Host |    Host | 2.9743 ns | 0.0541 ns |
     C8 |      X64 |    RyuJit |      Host |    Host | 2.6280 ns | 0.1526 ns |
     C2 |      X86 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 3.0854 ns | 0.2172 ns |
     C3 |      X86 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 3.1627 ns | 0.1126 ns |
     C4 |      X86 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 3.0577 ns | 0.0929 ns |
     C5 |      X86 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 5.0957 ns | 0.1601 ns |
     C6 |      X86 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 6.1723 ns | 0.1177 ns |
     C7 |      X86 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 7.1155 ns | 0.0803 ns |
     C8 |      X86 | LegacyJit |      Host |    Host | 3.7703 ns | 0.1276 ns |
```

[image]

Full source code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes.Exporters;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

[LegacyJitX86Job, LegacyJitX64Job, RyuJitX64Job, MonoJob]
[RPlotExporter]
public class CardBenchmarks
{
  public const int Size = 256;

  private float[] result, one;
  private Cards2[] cards2;
  private Cards3[] cards3;
  private Cards4[] cards4;
  private Cards5[] cards5;
  private Cards6[] cards6;
  private Cards7[] cards7;
  private Cards8[] cards8;

  [Setup]
  public void Setup()
  {
    result = ArrayUtils.CreateRandomFloatArray(Size);
    one = ArrayUtils.CreateRandomFloatArray(size: 52);
    var c0 = ArrayUtils.RandomByteArray(Size, minValue: 0, maxValueInclusive: 51);
    var c1 = ArrayUtils.RandomByteArray(Size, minValue: 0, maxValueInclusive: 51);

    cards2 = CardUtls.Create2(c0, c1);
    cards3 = CardUtls.Create3(c0, c1);
    cards4 = CardUtls.Create4(c0, c1);
    cards5 = CardUtls.Create5(c0, c1);
    cards6 = CardUtls.Create6(c0, c1);
    cards7 = CardUtls.Create7(c0, c1);
    cards8 = CardUtls.Create8(c0, c1);
  }

  [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = Size)]
  public void C2()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards2[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
  }

  [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = Size)]
  public void C3()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards3[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
  }

  [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = Size)]
  public void C4()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards4[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
  }

  [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = Size)]
  public void C5()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards5[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
  }

  [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = Size)]
  public void C6()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards6[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
  }

  [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = Size)]
  public void C7()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards7[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
  }

  [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = Size)]
  public void C8()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = cards8[i];
      result[i] -= one[c.C0] + one[c.C1];
    }
  }
}

public static class ArrayUtils
{
  private static readonly Random Rand = new Random(137);

  public static float[] CreateRandomFloatArray(int size)
  {
    var result = new float[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      result[i] = (float) Rand.NextDouble();
    return result;
  }

  public static byte[] RandomByteArray(int size, int minValue, int maxValueInclusive)
  {
    var result = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      result[i] = (byte) Rand.Next(minValue, maxValueInclusive + 1);
    return result;
  }
}

public static class CardUtls
{
  private static T[] Create<T>(int length, Func<int, T> create) => Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(create).ToArray();

  public static Cards2[] Create2(byte[] c0, byte[] c1) => Create(c0.Length, i => new Cards2 {C0 = c0[i], C1 = c1[i]});
  public static Cards3[] Create3(byte[] c0, byte[] c1) => Create(c0.Length, i => new Cards3 {C0 = c0[i], C1 = c1[i]});
  public static Cards4[] Create4(byte[] c0, byte[] c1) => Create(c0.Length, i => new Cards4 {C0 = c0[i], C1 = c1[i]});
  public static Cards5[] Create5(byte[] c0, byte[] c1) => Create(c0.Length, i => new Cards5 {C0 = c0[i], C1 = c1[i]});
  public static Cards6[] Create6(byte[] c0, byte[] c1) => Create(c0.Length, i => new Cards6 {C0 = c0[i], C1 = c1[i]});
  public static Cards7[] Create7(byte[] c0, byte[] c1) => Create(c0.Length, i => new Cards7 {C0 = c0[i], C1 = c1[i]});
  public static Cards8[] Create8(byte[] c0, byte[] c1) => Create(c0.Length, i => new Cards8 {C0 = c0[i], C1 = c1[i]});
}

public struct Cards2
{
  public byte C0, C1;
}

public struct Cards3
{
  public byte C0, C1, C2;
}

public struct Cards4
{
  public byte C0, C1, C2, C3;
}

public struct Cards5
{
  public byte C0, C1, C2, C3, C4;
}

public struct Cards6
{
  public byte C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5;
}

public struct Cards7
{
  public byte C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6;
}

public struct Cards8
{
  public byte C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7;
}


class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    BenchmarkRunner.Run<CardBenchmarks>();
  }
}
```

#### Answer

As you can see, your benchmark is a hard one, there are a lot of different factors which affect your performance. One of the most important things is how your runtime layouts your data. For example, you will not observe the described behavior on Mono, because Mono and the Full Framework have different layout algorithms (on Mono we have `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Card2)) == 8`).

We have `Time(Card5) > Time(Card8)` on the Full Framework because `Card5` produces a lot of unaligned reads unlike `Card8` (see the first picture).

### Update

Question from [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949304/accessing-5-byte-struct-is-much-slower-than-8-byte/39074248#comment65509087_39074248):

> Any idea why 3-byte performs better than 8-byte on your RyuJIT64 benchmark?

Let's look at the asm code:

```
; RyuJIT-x64, C3
                var c = cards3[i];
00007FFEDF0CADCE  mov         r10,r9  
00007FFEDF0CADD1  mov         r11d,dword ptr [r10+8]  
00007FFEDF0CADD5  cmp         eax,r11d  
00007FFEDF0CADD8  jae         00007FFEDF0CAE44  
00007FFEDF0CADDA  movsxd      r11,eax  
00007FFEDF0CADDD  imul        r11,r11,3  
00007FFEDF0CADE1  lea         r10,[r10+r11+10h]  
00007FFEDF0CADE6  movzx       r11d,byte ptr [r10]          ; !!!
00007FFEDF0CADEA  movzx       r10d,byte ptr [r10+1]        ; !!!

; RyuJIT-x64, C8
                var c = cards8[i];
00007FFEDF0CAE8C  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rcx+48h]  
00007FFEDF0CAE90  mov         r8d,dword ptr [rdx+8]  
00007FFEDF0CAE94  cmp         eax,r8d  
00007FFEDF0CAE97  jae         00007FFEDF0CAF0C  
00007FFEDF0CAE99  movsxd      r8,eax  
00007FFEDF0CAE9C  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx+r8*8+10h] ; !!! 
00007FFEDF0CAEA1  mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rdx      ; !!!
```

In the `C3` case, RyuJIT keeps the target bytes in the `r11d`, `r10d` registers; in the `C8` case, RyuJIT keeps them on stack (`qword ptr [rsp+28h]`). The explanation: the current version of RyuJIT (v4.6.1080.0 in my case) does scalar replacement for structs with no more than 4 fields (see [coreclr#6839](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6839)). Thus, RyuJIT performance of `C5`, `C6`, `C7`, and `C8` is worse than performance of `C2`, `C3`, `C4`. Be careful: this behavior may be changed in the future versions of RyuJIT.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I suspected memory alignment because of how 8-byte performed vs 5-byte. Any idea why 3-byte performs better than 8-byte on your RyuJIT64 benchmark?

Comment: @Michal, here is the corresponded coreclr issue: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6839

Comment: That's explains it. It is some crude internal behavior in RyuJIT. It is quite shocking to me how the timings vary based on different compilers. For example Legacy64 for some reason performs awfully bad for 3-card. I'd expect that 5 and 7-card would cause similar misalignment issues, but the timing for 3-card stands out.

Comment: Also, assuming the 'scalar replacement' issue is fixed, can we expect to see the timings to be relatively uniform for RyuJIT? I mean, C2,C3,C4 have quite similar timings, and it looks like degradation in performance for C5 and above is due to that RyuJIT issue rather than memory misalignment. Anyway, thanks for the investigation. I find it bit depressing that performance can vary this much based on some internal compiler quirks.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that this has to do with memory alignment.

Technical Info:

Some architectures, for example MIPS architectures, can't actually modify just a single byte at a time in memory. they have to load a word of data into a register, mask out the irrelevant bits, and perform the calculation.

You may actually experience a speed up by using normal int's instead of bytes as it avoids this issue altogether.